# Add two or multiple functions in Wordpress Post or Page

Tags: php, customization, shortcode, mysql, actions

I have a website that uses WordPress.
I would like to add in a post or a page a login code for an external database, code that uses two functions: 1. connect to the database 2. login form.
I don't know how to do that, because if I add the code in a post, after doing the first action it halts. In the first php code I see that it calls another file, file that exists on server but after calling the file it halts.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Both "pages" and "posts" are individual entries in the `wp_posts` database table - you can't put executable PHP code in either. Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help] for some guidelines for improving your question

Comment: I am sorry. I would like to know if there is any way to add executable PHP code in a post. I thought it is a plugin or something that would help me do that.

Comment: A [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress%20php%20in%20page&rct=j) turns up some results. But please note that [plugin recommendations are off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It's definitely possible to add the ability to execute PHP code via shortcode (or otherwise) yourself, however we ask that questions show a considerable amount of research and implementation effort on the asker's part. As it stands, it's unclear what you've tried thus far, and what problem you're running into.

Comment: I did some research and all I could find didn't help me because that php code didn't run the way it should. I used the php code in a shortcode but that also didn't run how it should.

Comment: Let's look at this in a different way. It sounds like you want a specific page to show some stuff based on some data from a different, non-WordPress database - is that correct? In short, what's the bigger goal that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, on a specific page I want to show a login form. That login form should create users in a database, but not the database that contains users from wordpress site such as admins or moderators.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a custom page template. Within that template, you can check for POSTed variables. Something to the effect of:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Login form
 */
if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {
    // check credentials and if valid display data
} else {
    // display login form
}
```

Once you've created this file and uploaded it in your theme files (preferably a child theme, if you are not using a custom-built theme; save it as something like `tpl-login.php` for easy reference) you can create a Page in WordPress and there will be a dropdown to select the template. Select this "Login form" template, publish the page or save a draft, and you can continue editing your page template until it performs all the functions you need.